# R: Conditionally mutating a variable (tricky)

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

We are currently working on a project for school, and we do not have that much experience with coding and R. The dataset that we are working on contains the variable operationtype, which has a lot of combinations between several operation types. We want to recode this into the variable operationcategory. These are the categories we want to recode the many operations into:

```
"AVR/P+other"
"AVR/P+MVP/R+other"
"MVR/P+other"
"CABG+other"
"CABG+AVR/P+other"
"CABG+MVR/P+other"
 If none of above then >   ~ "Remaining"
```

We were wondering if this can be done somewhat automatically, where we can specify the following for AVR/P+other: If it includes AVR/P, however does not include MVP/R then classify as AVR/P+other, if it does include MVP/R then classify as "AVR/P+MVP/R+other". Since these are two categories that are closely related. Doing this by hand would take forever, so hopefully this is possible.

Thank you for your help in advance.
Koen

Comment: this can be easily done in R. Check out the `case_when` function and the `grepl` function.
If provide part of your data (you can do this using `dput(head(mydata))`) we can give you more details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that operationtype contains the exact string, what I would probably do is something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

    transformed_df <- df %>%
       mutate(operationcategory = case_when(str_detect(operationtype, "AVR/P") & str_detect(operationtype, "MVP/R") ~ "AVR/P+MVP/R+other", 
                                   str_detect(operationtype, "AVR/P") ~ "AVR/P+other", 
                                   TRUE ~ "Remaining"))
```

Just beware that they are evaluated as they come, so the most restrictive contidions should be on top.

You could use regular expressions to use a single `str_detect`, but this is probably easier to understand and use.